# Why won't this string convert to dict?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, flask

I have a small flask app that I'm using to import jobs from a database. The route I use for importing the jobs is as follows (job_details is a submit button in a form for each individual job that passes the job):

```
@app.route("/job-import", methods=["POST"])
def job_import():
    if "loggedin" in session:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            job = request.form['job_details']

            # Job comes in string format, therefore needs to be converted to DICT
                job = ast.literal_eval(job)
...
```

I want to convert the string I get from `request.form['job_details']` to a dict so I can then parse it and access the values via `job['description'], job['title']` etc. However, I keep getting a 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' error. I am sure it is being passed as a string, and as far as I can find `ast.literal_eval()` should convert the string to a dict, however this is clearly not the case. Why is this?

Some sample input for a job from my app:

`"{'id': 3, 'date': datetime.date(2022, 2, 3), 'job_title': 'Cool title', 'contact_name': 'Mr Cool', 'contact_email': 'coolio@coolcom.cool', 'location': 'Coolville', 'expiry_date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 1), 'salary': None, 'twitter': None, 'listing_type': None, 'description': 'a cool job for cool people to do cool things', 'url': 'cooljobs.cool', 'logo': None, 'status': None}"`

Full traceback:

return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "", line 2450, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "", line 1867, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File "", line 39, in reraise raise value
File "", line 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "", line 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "", line 39, in reraise raise value
File "", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "", line 1936, in dispatch_request return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint
File "", line 57, in app if job['listing_type'] == "Basic job listing (free)":

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` only evaluates *literals*.  It does not evaluate function calls like `datetime.date(2022, 2, 3)`.  (I would expect a rather different error message from this, so it's apparently not the only problem you have.)

Comment: Yes, I actually did some tests with this and it looks like the datetime.date doesn't affect the error

Comment: Then post the full traceback message, so we can tell where it's happening.

Comment: I've edited the post with the full traceback message. I tried to format it to be more readable but apparently, it didn't like that. I've removed the file path and just left "" but everything else is copied directly from my exception log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since worked on this and solved the issue. In all honesty, I am not sure how. I ended up using ast.literal_eval and this has worked thus far and my program is working correctly as of now. I did not however change the datetime.date value in the database, although in future I think I will avoid this type as a rule of thumb.

Thank you to everyone who gave advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is sending back json then you should `json.loads` instead of `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: json.loads() gives the same error. I had tested this as well before posting the question.

Comment: Then your string isn't valid JSON. Did you add the quotes around the JSON blob? Can you show us the RAW json text?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this?

[`ast.literal_eval` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, `None` and `Ellipsis`.

Your string is holding `datetime.date` (`datetime.date(2022, 2, 3)`) which is not one of enumerated

Comment: Please see my comment under the original post